# AS3 text to file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file, overwrite

I'm making a game in cs3 using as3. I've seen dozens of tutorials, but none of them are working for me.
I found the simplest code I could, and it still gives me an error "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method save through a reference with static type flash.net:FileReference."

here's the code I'm using:

var file:FileReference = new FileReference();

file.save("this is a text", "file.txt")

Comment: In Flash Player 10 and Flash Player 9 Update 5, you can only call this method successfully in response to a user event (for example, in an event handler for a mouse click or keypress event). Otherwise, calling this method results in Flash Player throwing an Error exception.

Comment: okay is there an onLoad event?

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing FileReference? If not, you'll need:

```
import flash.net.FileReference;
```

..inside your package declaration (or at the top of your block of code if you're coding on the time line)
With that import included, your code works for me.

Comment: I didn't have any imports, but it didn't change the error when I added it.